# what is the meaning of getDialog.getWindow in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, dialog

I read some code where the x,y coordinates of a dialog are set like this:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams p = getWindow().getAttributes();
p.y = location[1] + switchSelector.getHeight();
int switchSelectorMidBottomXPosition = switchSelector.getWidth() / 2 + location[0];
p.x = switchSelectorMidBottomXPosition - mToolTipLayout.getWidth() + 2 * pxsRightToArrow;
```

what is the meaning of getDialog.getWindow ?

why not just layout **params** of `getDialog` ?

Answer (score 0):

getDialog() simply returns the private variable mDialog from the DialogFragment. whereas getDialog.getWindow is manually appears to have the newly set size Dialog.